# Hyperlinks from Magento 2 Email Templates to Outlook Destop are Gray not Blue. Please help!

Tags: magento2

I cannot figure out why all our our emails from our Magento 2 store like order confirmations, contact us emails have grey colored hyperlinks.

See screenshot as an example:
https://gyazo.com/a225a0a5014e50f725555436a8dfbdee

Now if I check this email in Gmail via a browser the links will look blue like a hyperlink should look.  I've talked with tech support at Outlook and they cannot figure it out.  Its not an outlook issue because I can get emails from everywhere else and hyperlinks look blue. Its only email from our Magento 2 store that come to outlook desktop where hyperlinks are grey colored.

Here is a screenshot of our contact us template:
https://gyazo.com/1e9e4c80c282cbbd9da1d71621aa25c8

Our developer i think tried to add color to areas and that hasn't fixed the issue either.  I also created a new template for our contact us page and test it and everything came to outlook with grey hyperlinks.

Again I can check the same contact us email in Gmail online https://gyazo.com/4ebdb9e8c141b1c5df950aed4ed9d7d6 and it will show blue hyperlinks but in outlook they always show up grey colored from our Magento 2 store only.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that outlook isn’t rendering the links as if you’ve visited the page before (a:visited in CSS)?

Comment: I'll ask outlook tech support when they call back next week.  thx

Comment: Outlook Tier 3 support said its not Outlook causing this.. Its definitely in something in Magento 2 that is doing this.  Also the only time I have this issue is from any email forms coming from our Magento 2 website.  All other sourced emails have blue hyperlinks.  Any other ideas?